# How is the off-topic sites list generated?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, off-topic

Many times I find a question which does not belong to SO, and I want to flag it as **off topic** then I get a list of websites as shown in the screenshot bellow:

> [image]

My question is how this list of websites created ? and what can I do if I wanted to mention a website which is not listed there ?

For the instant I have a question which I wanted to flag it as bellowing to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but it is **not listed** !

Comment: It's comprised of the site's Meta and up to four of the most commonly migrated-to-and-accepted sites. - What makes you think the question belongs on Programmers so much? You don't even have any activity on that site. That's the reason it's *not* listed. Too many bad questions got migrated there and rejected.

Comment: The list is not generated automatically.

Comment: What makes me think the question belongs to Programmers is that its an algorithmic issue without any programming language assigned

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd is it a static list ?

Comment: I believe animuson gave you an answer via the comments...

Comment: You can flag questions using the custom "other" flag and explain your reasoning to the moderators. They can migrate questions to any site in the network.

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae: Having no programming language does not automatically make it off-topic. Software algorithms *are* on-topic for Stack Overflow. Algorithm *concepts* are on-topic for Programmers.

Comment: yes I agree @animuson, and I think its an _Algorithm Concepts_ more than a _Software algorithm_

Comment: I disagree on this being a duplicate of the target question, btw. This asks primarily about *which* sites show up there. This is something that I don't see answered on the dupe target.

Comment: Yes @FEichinger is there a way to complain about it ?

Comment: Yes, I have cast a reopen vote because I don't think this is a duplicate. Now if enough people vote it reopen it will be reopened :)

Comment: I often find mathematics questions on StackOverflow (for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16206026/1858225, to which I gave a quick answer anyway just so the person could get on with their life). It would be nice to be able to explicitly flag these questions as belonging where they actually belong.

Answer (score 4):

The list is generated by Stack Exchange employees, using suggestions from the site moderators and statistics on migrations.

Moderators can migrate questions to sites not on the list but as @animuson commented, your question may not deserve to be migrated to Programmers. Flag it and comment where you think it should go.