# Review the list of site for off-topic question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic, migrated-questions

When I want to vote to close a question, most of the time, the target site will be

1. [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
2. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

And that's pretty all. The list propose me site like [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) and [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).
The good news is that I can close off-topic for SuperUser, it is in the list. But Code Review never appear.

Is there a reason why SharePoint and Tex are present? I mean I never need to off-topic for this site. Whereas question belonging to Code Review never stop to come.

What are the criteria that make a site visible in the 5 items list?  (Edit, answer here : [How is the off-topic sites list generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175423/how-is-the-off-topic-sites-list-generated))

Can we include Code Review by replacing it with Tex or Share Point?

Related questions:

- [Could we have Code Review be one of the list of off-topic closing options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109517/could-we-have-code-review-be-one-of-the-list-of-off-topic-closing-options)
- [Option to move post from Stackoverflow to codereview.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange)

Comment: [We don't ever want to show more than 5 here, because it gets overwhelming.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345/166025)

Comment: Short answer: meh. Those are the common ones. If question is unquestionably good, then flag a mod to move it.

Comment: If you find something that is a better fit for Code Review, just flag it and explain that you want to see it migrated. Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange

Comment: @Bart : What is the best, vote to close as off-topic, flag to migrate to Code Review, or both?

Comment: Code Review is still in beta, or did I miss something?

Comment: @MadScientist : In fact it is. I miss something too, my apologies!

Comment: @MadScientist Nope, you didn't miss anything. Still Beta, so not going to be a target afaik.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that @hims056; the OP is asking for one of the 5 to be replaced not for more options. It might be a duplicate of the question linked by Bart, though it's fairly old now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might now be an argument for including Code Review in place of Sharepoint. Code Review has edged in front on moderator migrations alone. **However**, once you take rejected migrations into account Sharepoint is still in front.

There are hardly any migrations to either but Code Review rejects more. You can always flag and a moderator will migrate for you. There's no need to change the list of options (yet).

Here's the latest migration stats:

> [image]

The list itself is [decided by Stack Exchange employees](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175423/how-is-the-off-topic-sites-list-generated); though a community can request a change:

- [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)
- [Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f)

Comment: Never thought Tex and Sharepoint were this much represented. It make a lot more sense now!

Comment: CR is still Beta though. And unless this has changed, migration paths to Beta sites are not possible.

Comment: Yes, I didn't add that due to your comment linking to the relevant question @Bart. There's also never been an authoritative answer to that question...